# list of methods for use with android NativeActivity

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, native-methods

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all the native c/c++ methods and functions for use with the android NativeActivity. I cant seem to find a list anywhere on the google/android site and Ive been googling it for the past two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for **NativeActivity** can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html).  That is the **Java** side of the API, but the native side's documentation is a bit harder to find.  [This](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/NATIVE-ACTIVITY.HTML) is a link to a doc about the native activity, which can be found in the 'docs' folder of the NDK as well.  Additionally, the **native_activity.h** contains all of the C Android framework callbacks you'd expect, with their documentation and, naturally, method signatures.  It can be found in the NDK in, e.g., *\android-ndk-r6b\platforms\android-9\arch-x86\usr\include\android*.
Hope this helps you a little more than my original answer!

EDIT: Added more documentation info.

Comment: Ive looked at those before but are those the actual native methods to be used in c/c++ ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion-- edited my answer to provide a little more detail :)